# "all evening today" vs. any better variants

Tags: construction

Does it sound natural if I say --

> My neighbor has been playing loud music in their apartment **all evening today**
> .

Or

> My neighbor has been playing loud music in their apartment **the whole time this evening**.

Or are there any better ways to say this?

Comment: "*... all evening.*" It's understood that it's "today" because the tense is present.

Comment: You _could_ say **all this evening**, but, as gotube says, 'today' is understood.

Comment: I see. Thank you both for helping!